# ListString to string with GSON - TypeToken

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to parse a JSON Array in my Android App with some URLs in it to load into my SQLite DB, here is the code:

```
JSONArray pics = json.getJSONArray("bilder");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String obj = gson.toJson(pics);
String SQLiteDataBaseQuery = "INSERT INTO images_table (id,desc,imgurl) VALUES('"+i+"', '"+jr_desc+"', '"+obj+"');";
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDataBaseQuery);
```

Reading out the DB with the Emulator I can see the String {"values":[URLS here]}. Is it normal that GSON writes this "values" in front of my String List?

So, now I want to call the information from my DB:

```
Cursor cursor;
Array_links = new ArrayList<String>();
SQLiteGallery sqLiteHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteGallery(this);
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+SQLiteGallery.TAB_NAME+"", null);
cursor.moveToPosition(0);
Array_links.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteGallery.table_imgurl)));
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>().getType();
List<String> img_urls = gson.fromJson(Array_links,type);
for(String url : img_urls)
{
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Android Studio gives me the following error:

> TypeToken has protected access in 'com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken'

What does that mean? Is my code wrong?

Thank you

Correct Code here:

```
     Cursor cursor;
     String urls;
     SQLiteGallery sqLiteHelper;
     SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
     sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteGallery(this);
     sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 
     "+SQLiteGallery.TAB_NAME+"", null);
     cursor.moveToPosition(0);
     urls = 
     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteGallery.table_imgurl));
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
     List<String> img_urls = gson.fromJson(urls,type);
     for(String url : img_urls)
     {
     System.out.println(url);
     }
```

Error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting the `{}`, your code is:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>().getType();
```

It should be:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
```

Comment: Thank you, now the Error is in the next line: "List<String> img_urls = gson.fromJson(Array_links,type);" - Cannot resolve method 'fromJson(java.util.ArrayList<>,java.lang.reflect(Type)'. Is it because Array Links is defined Array and not String List?

Comment: when using `gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);` the `jsonString` must be a string generated from the same type object of the `type`. So, if `jsonString` is from List<String> then the `type` must also from List<string>

Comment: Did a edit on my Post, now the Code seems to read the Cell, but there is a new Error in Android Studio where I don't get what it is about.

Comment: @ibai.kar: your `urls` is a string not a List of string.

Comment: Ok maybe there is a problem in my understanding of GSON: INPUT: I'm reading a JSONArray, then GSON puts it into a String which gets saved in my SQLite DB in one single Cell. OUTPUT: now I'm reading it from my DB - the Cursor hops to line 0 in column table_imgurl, it puts the content of the cell to "urls" which is basically a String. Now with GSON / Type I should be able to convert my String back to List of String, right? Therefor why shouldn't I define Type as List of String if I want that as my final form?

Comment: I'm very sorry. Your understanding is right. Please ignore my previous comment. The problem probably because your string isn't from the gson result.

Comment: Can you please help me with that? How should the code look like?